# api route laravel always return error 400

Tags: laravel, api, routes

I have route api.php like so

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.verify']], function() {
    Route::get('logout', [ApiController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::get('pengguna', [ApiController::class, 'getAuthenticatedUser']);
    Route::get('get_kabupaten/{provid}', [KabupatenController::class, 'get_kabupaten']);
    Route::get('get_kecamatan/{kabid}', [KecamatanController::class, 'get_kecamatan']);
    Route::get('get_kelurahan/{kecid}', [DesaController::class, 'get_kelurahan']); 
    Route::get('get_bencana', [JenisbencanaController::class, 'get_bencana']); 
    Route::get('saport', [ReportController::class, 'get_laporan']);
      Route::post('saport/create', [ReportController::class, 'store']);
    Route::get('saport/{id}', [ReportController::class, 'show']);
   
    // Route::get('laporan', [LaporanController::class, 'get_laporan']);
  
    // Route::post('laporan/create', [LaporanController::class, 'store']);
    // Route::get('laporan/{id}', [LaporanController::class, 'show']);
    // Route::put('update/{product}',  [LaporanController::class, 'update']);
    // Route::delete('delete/{product}',  [LaporanController::class, 'destroy']);
});
```

all everything else work except

```
 Route::get('pengguna', [ApiController::class, 'getAuthenticatedUser']);
 Route::get('saport', [ReportController::class, 'get_laporan']);
 Route::post('saport/create', [ReportController::class, 'store']);
 Route::get('saport/{id}', [ReportController::class, 'show']);
```

and this my reportcontroller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Laporan;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Auth;
class ReportController extends Controller
{
    
    public function get_laporan()
    {
    
        $laporan=Laporan::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();;
        return response()->json(compact('laporan'));
    
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      
        $data = $request->only( 'desa_id','bencana_id','koordinat','korban_kk','korban_orang','sebab_bencana');
        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'desa_id' => 'required',
            'bencana_id' => 'required',
            'koordinat' => 'required',
            'korban_kk' => 'required',
            'korban_orang' => 'required',
            'sebab_bencana' => 'required',
           
        ]);

        //Send failed response if request is not valid
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->messages()], 200);
        }

        $laporan = new Laporan;
        $laporan->bencana_id = $request->bencana_id;
        $laporan->desa_id= $request->desa_id;
        $laporan->koordinat= $request->koordinat;
        $laporan->user_id= Auth::id();
        $laporan->korban_kk= $request->korban_kk;
        $laporan->korban_orang= $request->korban_orang;
        $laporan->sebab_bencana= $request->sebab_bencana;
        $laporan->bantuan_diperlukan= $request->bantuan_diperlukan;
        $laporan->respon_instansi= $request->respon_instansi;
        $laporan->lokasi_pengungsian= $request->lokasi_pengungsian;
        $laporan->pengungsi_kk= $request->pengungsi_kk;
        $laporan->pengungsi_orang= $request->pengungsi_orang;
        $laporan->permintaan_bantuan= $request->permintaan_bantuan;
        $laporan->save();


        
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'laporan telah di input',
            'data' => $laporan
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $laporan=Laporan::where('user_id', Auth::id())->find($id);;
        if (!$laporan) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Sorry, Laporan not found.'
            ], 400);
        }
    
        return response()->json(compact('laporan'));

    }

}
```

i have rename int from laporan to report to saport, create new controller, and make it HTTPS for saport always return 400.
as far as i know the structure of controler the same with other controller, couse i use meke:controller, and why it return 400  400 Bad Request.

and i make new basic  route, and it return 400

```
Route::get('saport', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

cahche:clear

route:clear

dumptautoload

trying remove saport from outside jwt,verify

all return 400

i have try all.

btw in local it run like charm, it case only in sharehosting.

Answer (score -1):

i think it postman issue, not laravel. but if any solve for it issue please tell me